# Is it possible to create a Ruby extension wrapping a CLOSED SOURCE C++ library?

Tags: c++, ruby

- Extension wrapping C lib: simple
- Extension wrapping C++ lib where source is available:  rb++, etc
- Extension wrapping C++ CLOSED SOURCE lib: ??

There seems to be plenty of information for situations where all source is available, but I can't seem to find advice for this explicit situation.

Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, just link your extension to the distributed library or DLL and have your extension use the interface of that library.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, if you have the headers of the closed library.

Comment: Depending on exactly how ruby extensions work, you may need to write a little C++ wrapper around the closed source lib, and use that as your ruby extension.